# why i got index out of bound exeption:invalid array range 0 to 0?

Tags: arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

```
public static void main(String[] args){
     Random ran = new Random();
     int nums[][];
     nums = new int[3][5];

     for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
         for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
             nums=new int[i][j];
             nums[i][j]=1+ran.nextInt(90);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nums=new int[i][j]
```

Here your are creating an array with length i and y
And the next line `nums=new int[i][j]`
you are trying the access last index but index start with index 0 to length -1
You should use nums=new int[i-1][j-1] to fetch last index

Answer (score 0):

On the first iteration of the cycle you call the line: `nums = new int[i][j]`, but i and j are 0. So in essence you are calling `nums = new int[0][0]` and this is not a valid statement.

I think what you meant to do is to allocate the array once(outside the double cycle as you do on line 4) and only assign values in the cycles. Try removing the line `nums = new int[i][j]` and see if this is what you expect. I don't get what you are trying to achieve with this statement.

Comment: Please refrain from posting 'Thank you' comments. The right way to mark the solution that worked for you is to accept the answer. You may also upvote all answers that you find helpful. This helps future readers resolve similar issues.